# SharpDocx - foreach statement shows only last element of list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ms-word, docx

I'm using SharpDocx to generate a docx file from a template, using my custom model. Everything works fine except the `foreach` statement that returns only the last element of my list regardless i got a few more.

Model:

```
public class ReportDocxModel
{
    public ReportDocxModel()
    {
        Contatti = new List<Contatti>();
    }

    public List<Contatti> Contatti { get; set; }
}
```

Method to generate the document:

```
var document = DocumentFactory.Create(filePath, model);
document.Generate(Path.Combine(rootPath, tempFileName));
```

Segment inside the template (extension cs.docx) where i loop my list
[image]

I followed the example and the demo [here](https://github.com/egonl/SharpDocx) but it doesn't work. I'm on Asp.NET Core 3.1 and SharpDocx version is 1.2.1 (latest)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't quite follow the example, since you forgot `<% AppendRow(); %>` after `<%= c.Email %>`. If you don't call AppendRow(), no rows will be appended to the table. That's why you only see a table with one row, containing the last element.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment. It is not a fully formed answer.

Comment: It's indeed better suited as a comment, but he discovered the reason why it didn't work for me, so i'm gonna mark it as correct answer anyway